# .reduce() creates double quotes for object's values how to remove them?

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically feed an axios.post data with an object containing key-value pairs where the key is a string and the value is a command. The output should be like so:

```
{
'gear_categories_id': document.querySelector('#gear_categories_id').value,   
'sub_categories_id': document.querySelector('#sub_categories_id').value, 
//etc
}
```

So I have created a function that iterates through the DOM and gets all the different input's names when user clicks "submit" then used .reduce() to create the object out of the Array (only relevant part copied):

```
let namesArray = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("inpt").length; i++) {
      let name= document.getElementsByClassName("inpt")[i].getAttribute("name");
      namesArray.push(name);
      }
      let namesObject = namesArray.reduce((a,b,)=>(a[`'${b}'`]=`document.querySelector('#${b}').value`, a),{});
```

The problem is that JS adds automatically double quotes to the object's values and I can't use .replace with regex while inside .reduce, so the result looks like this:

```
'gear_categories_id': "document.querySelector('#gear_categories_id').value"
```

instead of like this:

```
'gear_categories_id': document.querySelector('#gear_categories_id').value
```

I've looked for the answer all over and all I can find is stuff that is meant for JSON and this is a plain JS object NOT JSON other answers suggest .replace(/"/g,"") that won't work while the object is being "cooked" by the .reduce()

Any ideas on how to remove the double quotes during the creation of the object? Or how to remove them only from the values after the object is being created?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect, since `'gear_categories_id': document.querySelector('#gear_categories_id').value` is not a valid value. Do you want the *result* of `document.querySelector('#gear_categories_id').value` to be assigned to the key or what?

Comment: It is 100% valid value and it works in axios.post without a problem if the object is as mentioned. You're welcome to try and see for yourself.

Comment: You can use `eval` on the corresponding value of each `key`. For Eg., `eval("document.querySelector('#gear_categories_id')")`.

Comment: @NithishGandesiri why use `eval` instead of just directly evaluating it?

Comment: _"Any ideas on how to remove the double quotes during the creation of the object?"_ - There are no actual _"double quotes"_. The value of the property is a string (more precisely the result of a template literal) and your browser/console uses double quotes to wrap that string for output.

Comment: @nurge It's *NOT A VALUE*. What you have is an *expression* inside an object literal. It will be evaluated and resolved. Same as if having `{foo: 1+1}` you don't assign the "value* `1+1` to `foo`, you assign the result of the evaluated expression. If you don't want this to be string but to evaluate it, then *don't make it a string*. Just remove the `\`` characters around it.

Comment: I agree @VLAZ but I'm not exactly sure why it's been stored as a string. Hence I mentioned `eval`. If there's no requirement of storing as string then directly evaluating will work perfectly.

Comment: @VLAZ see example on how this works in here: https://youtu.be/10uUnaKgVeo I have a similar case of trying to validate a form in Laravel but my form is being created dynamically and has bits of DOM from other views so I need to iterate through all inputs to get the name attributes and feed them to axios for validation.

Comment: @nurge Instead of `let namesObject = namesArray.reduce((a,b,)=>(a[`'${b}'`]=`document.querySelector('#${b}').value`, a),{});`, try this `let namesObject = namesArray.reduce((a,b,)=>(a[`'${b}'`]=document.querySelector('#${b}').value, a),{});`

Comment: @VLAZ the ``` doesn't turn the expression into a string it's to make it escape all cases of quotes and double quotes and that is why I express variables like so `${variable}` within it.

Comment: @nurge a 30 minute video? No thanks. I've explained it already - if you want the *result* of evaluating `document.querySelector('#gear_categories_id').value` then don't make it into a string. This means don't do `\`document.querySelector('#${b}').value\`` - the backticks around that turn it into a string. If you don't need the evaluated expression, then I don't know how to help you as it's impossible to have a value that's a literal `document.querySelector('#gear_categories_id').value`. Such a thing doesn't exist.

Comment: @nurge "*the [`] doesn't turn the expression into a string*" [it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). EDIT: [example](https://jsbin.com/koqumep/edit?js,console)

Comment: @VLAZ, & Nithish Thanks I will try and get back to you

Comment: @VLAZ actually all the elements @nurge is looping are  the input elements hence `document.querySelector('#gear_categories_id').value` is working for him. As you said it might not be available on all the HTML elements.

Comment: @NithishGandesiri - Your solution doesn't work at all and turns variables into strings

Comment: Ok it is now obvious that it is not possible to prevent the double quotes coming from reduce() so the solution could only be removing them AFTER object was created. Anyone knows how to do that? .replace() doesn't seem to work on objects...

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle link or any working example. May be then we'll be able to help.

Comment: Instead of making false assumptions and asking for a workaround that isn't needed, try to understand what has been already said in the comments. Your expected output doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of what you are actually looking for. 
`namesObject` will have the keys as the `input` element `name`s or `id`s and the corresponding values are the actual data entered in the `inputs`.

```js
let namesArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("inpt").length; i++) {
  let name= document.getElementsByClassName("inpt")[i].getAttribute("name");
  namesArray.push(name);
}

let namesObject = namesArray.reduce((a,b,)=>(a[`'${b}'`] = document.querySelector(`#${b}`).value, a),{});

console.log(namesObject)
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="inpt" id="input_1" type="text" name="input_1"/>
<input class="inpt" id="input_2" type="text" name="input_2" value="test 2"/>
</div>
```

Hope this helps in order to fulfil your requirement.